# Text Alignment Not Centered MoviePy

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I want to create a subtitleclip that's position on the video is little right to the center but, the text should be aligned to the center.

So here's my code

```
    generator = lambda txt, font_size: TextClip(txt, font='Arial-Rounded-MT-Bold', fontsize=font_size, color='white', align="center")
    subs = [(text, start_end, font_size) for (start_end, text, font_size) in words]
    subtitles = SubtitlesClip(subs, generator)
    subtitles = subtitles.set_pos((950, 'center'))
```

The position works fine, subtitles show as it supposed to, but the aligment of those textclip is to the left even through I have added align = 'center' in the code. The aligment stays centered when I use the position like the following,

```
subtitles = subtitles.set_pos(('center', 'center'))
```

But it goes to left aligment when I change the x position value.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the `align` attribute you should add `method='caption'` too.

```
generator = lambda txt, font_size: TextClip(txt, font='Arial-Rounded-MT-Bold', fontsize=font_size, color='white', align="center", method='caption')
    subs = [(text, start_end, font_size) for (start_end, text, font_size) in words]
    subtitles = SubtitlesClip(subs, generator)
    subtitles = subtitles.set_pos((950, 'center'))
```